# Display Success Message Box in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net

How can I display messagebox with success logo in ASP.net, I can only display alert message box by using these code.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Please dont leave text boxes blank');",true);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: can you able call javascript function like this ??? ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "myfunction();",true);

Comment: Thank you for this! will try this one

Comment: I do not think message boxes give a good experience in ASP.NET. I would tend to avoid anything that pops up, including a JS alert. A nice friendly message with red background at top or bottom of page is usually better.

Comment: @James You are right from a stilistic point of view. But IMO using a pop up and forcing the user to click on the "ok" button is the best way to make sure he is reciving the message and dedicanting a little bit of attention to it.

Comment: @Grirg Could use a modal JQuery or Bootrap pop up for that if you really needed, from the post though it looks like validation. Showing a message and disabling submit should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", " Student Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some notes on this, not just code posted.

Comment: The question is also for asp.net, not winforms.

Answer (score 0):

I Found This may Be It works...

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message Title", "Your Message", true);
```